# GET запрос, как часто можно выполнять? (20 и больше раз в секунду?)

Tags: php, get

Мне нужно отправлять данные с одного устройства на сервер с частотой 20 и более раз в секунду.

Было бы удобно это делать GET запросом.

Не будет ли подводных камней? Не воспримет ли провайдер это как атаку на сервер?

Спасибо!

Comment: не стоит GET запросом отправлять данные, некоторое оборудование да и браузеры кеширует GET запросы, так что до сервера они могут и не дойти

Comment: Используйте (веб)сокеты и не насилуйте бедный HTTP

Comment: Соединение с сервером занимает некоторое время. Подключаться и отключаться более 20 раз в секунду глупо, ибо у вас большая часть времени будет тратиться на подключение. Вам нужно выбирать технологии неразрывного соединения.

Answer (score 0):

Да хоть в каждую миллисекунду, главное чтобы сервер успел отвечать.

Get запрос не предназначен для отправки данных, большинство устройств кешиируют их